# Navigation bar won't show itself in a multi-paged tkinter application

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, navigationbar, multi-page-application

I can't get a navigation bar to show and hide itself. I'm using classes to seperate the code meant for each particular page.

I've tried the below code. I expected the navigation bar to show itself with buttons, that, when clicked - change the page.

I should be able to click on the nav button/menu button where it shows a drop down all pages available, allowing the user to then click on one of the buttons in the drop down to navigate to a page of their desire.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk 
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

def toggle_win(root):
    
    w = root

    f1 = Frame(w,width=300,height=600,bg='#12c4c0')
    f1.place(x=0,y=0)

    def bttn(x,y,text,bcolor,fcolor,cmd):

        def on_entera(e):
            MyButton1['background'] = bcolor
            MyButton1['foreground'] = "#262626"

        def on_leavea(e):
            MyButton1['background'] = fcolor
            MyButton1['foreground'] = "#262626"

        MyButton1 = Button(
            f1,
            text=text,
            width=42,
            height=2,
            fg="#262626",
            border=0,
            bg=fcolor,
            activeforeground="#262626",
            activebackground=bcolor,
            command=cmd
        )

        MyButton1.bind("<Enter>", on_entera)
        MyButton1.bind("<Leave>", on_leavea)

        MyButton1.place(x=x,y=y) 
    
    #    x,y, text,  bcolor,   fcolor,    cmd
    bttn(0,80,'Home','#0f9d9a','#12c4c0',None)
    bttn(0,117,'Two','#0f9d9a','#12c4c0',None)
    bttn(0,154,'Three','#0f9d9a','#12c4c0',None)
    bttn(0,191,'Four','#0f9d9a','#12c4c0',None)
    bttn(0,228,'Five','#0f9d9a','#12c4c0',None)
    bttn(0,265,'Six','#0f9d9a','#12c4c0',None)

    def dele():
        f1.destroy()
    
    global img2
    img2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('close.png'))

    Button(f1,image=img2,command=dele,border=0,activebackground='#12c4c0',bg="#12c4c0").place(x=0,y=0)


class ScrollableFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, *args, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(container, *args, **kwargs)

        canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
        self.scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)

        self.scrollable_frame.bind(
            "<Configure>",
            lambda e: canvas.configure(
                scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
            )
        )

        canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class Page1(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # Create a frame for the page based on the ScrollableFrame class
        frame = ScrollableFrame(self)
        frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        # Create x number of labels for this page
        for i in range(10):
            tk.Label(frame.scrollable_frame, text="Label {}".format(i)).pack()

class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # Create a frame for the page based on the ScrollableFrame class
        frame = ScrollableFrame(self)
        frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        # Create x number of labels for this page
        for i in range(10):
            tk.Label(frame.scrollable_frame, text="Label {}".format(i)).pack()

class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)
        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        # b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Scheduling Tools", command=p1.show)
        # b2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Data Cleansing Tools", command=p2.show)
        # #b1.pack(side="left")
        # #b2.pack(side="left")
        toggle_win(root=container)
        img1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('open.png'))
        button = Button(buttonframe,command=lb.toggle_win(root=container),image=img1,border=0,bg="#262626",activebackground='#262626')
        button.place(x=0,y=0)
        p1.show()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}")
    root.title("dmin tools")
    root.iconbitmap("python.ico")
    root.mainloop()

if "__main__" == __name__:
    main()
```

Comment: You are placing `p1` and `p2` at `0, 0` inside `container` same with your navigation bar. So both `p1` and `p2` are over your navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So I should place p1 and p2 in container at coordinates other than 0,0 and place the button variable at 0,0 ?

Comment: You can do that. Personally I don't like the Controller-Page system that people use with `tkinter`.

Comment: Can you recommend a better way to achieve the same/similar thing ?